# Some icons on the privileges pages are not aligned with the text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center

Some icons on the privileges pages are not aligned with the text:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user
  [image: Remove New User Restrictions]
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts
  [image: Flag Posts]

Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer.

---

The cause is this snippet of CSS:

```css
/* From http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=acd68c5e5301 */
.post-text img, .wmd-preview img {
    max-width: 630px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Is it related to the recent redesign?

Comment: Happens when viewing from my phone too! Good catch.

Comment: They did introduce that random `margin-bottom` in the redesign and no one can figure out why. It also makes regular posts look silly, especially if you place an image inside a blockquote.

Comment: @animuson good catch, I pushed a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix will go live after our next production build.